# mvvmcross example N-23 crashing

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog, ios8.1

My project is crashing very consistently on the device with (ios 8.1) when I do the following:

1. have MvxDialogViewController with 2 elements InputElement and any element that requires selection on the next screen (as an example DateElement)

   ```
       Root = new RootElement("The Dialog")
           {
               new Section("Section1")
                   {

                       new EntryElement("Value"),

                   },
               new Section("Section2")
                   {
                       new DateElement("Date", DateTime.Today),

                   },

           };
   ```
2. first set focus to EntryElement
3. click DateElemnt so that the screen will change
4. Once I click "GoBack" there is a crush. No errors. Just the whole app exists.

I took N-23 example as is and it has exactly the same problem.
Why is it happening? Works fine in simulator but not on a device.

Thank you

Mark

Comment: Do you mean crashing?

Comment: What does the console output from the crushed device say - is there SIGSEGV error info in there?

Comment: yes, crAshing is what I meant.

Comment: Stuart, I get the following error in vs.net output window MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSArrayM setRestorableResponder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b9cf10

Comment: Stuart, it seems that the problem related to keyboard dismissal. if I dismiss the keyboard first and then click date selector and come back - no crash.

Comment: 2014-11-05 15:44:35.939 N23DlgTouch[618:121176] -[NSLayoutConstraint setRestorableResponder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14cf820
Unhandled Exception:

Exact error message: 
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[NSLayoutConstraint setRestorableResponder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14cf820